# Merge two separate react app into a single app

Tags: reactjs, performance, merge, react-router, blockchain

I made two react apps using create-react-app, but now I need to merge both apps as a single app. I need to link my second app with the first when a button is clicked in the first app. How can I do that?

The first app has a login, signup and dashboard page.The second app has a form written in Solidity Blockchain. When I click 'Fill Details' button in Dashboard page, the second app form should be rendered!

I have no idea to do this. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Micro-fronted to merge two or more react apps and run together. The below below blog may be useful to you.
[How to develop microfrontend using react](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-develop-microfrontends-using-react-step-by-step-guide-47ebb479cacd)